# R: Replace multiple values based on multiple column value match of two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have two data.tables A and B, which have the same column names. A reproducible example is as below, where I show A first:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(cbind(x=c(45,45,45,50),
      y=c(97,98,100,102),
      N.x.y=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),
      N.x=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),
      N.y=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)))
```

This gives the following results:

```
    x   y N.x.y N.x N.y
1: 45  97   0.1 0.1 0.1
2: 45  98   0.1 0.1 0.1
3: 45 100   0.1 0.1 0.1
4: 50 102   0.1 0.1 0.1
```

And here is B:

```
as.data.table(cbind(x=c(45,50),
                    y=c(97,102),
                    N.x.y=c(0.3,0.4),
                    N.x=c(0.3,0.4),
                    N.y=c(0.3,0.4)))
```

Which gives this:

```
    x   y N.x.y N.x N.y
1: 45  97   0.3 0.3 0.3
2: 50 102   0.4 0.4 0.4
```

My goal is to update the values in the columns `N.x.y`, `N.x`, and `N.y` in data.table A if there exists a match of both `x` and `y` in data.table B.

The desired result would look like this:

```
    x   y N.x.y N.x N.y
1: 45  97   0.3 0.3 0.3
2: 45  98   0.1 0.1 0.1
3: 45 100   0.1 0.1 0.1
4: 50 102   0.4 0.4 0.4
```

I have experimented with the various join options offered by data.table, but I'm still not quite certain how this would ideally be done. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: try `cols = c('N.x.y','N.x','N.y'); A[B, on=.(x, y), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]`

Comment: the keyword for searching is update join. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdata.table%5D+%22update+join%22